# HTML Forms submit/buttons - fieldset or div

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Ok, I pretty much get the fieldset tag in html apart from two situations:

1. Should I use it if there will be only one element inside it (after all it is for 'grouping' form elements)
2. Should it be used to encapsulate a form submit button?  I typically use a div for this although I constantly wonder whether a fieldset would be better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. This is really a judgement call. I normally wouldn't use it if there was only one semantic group of elements, as the group is implicit, especially if there was only one element. A good example of semantic `fieldset` use might be to group the input fields of a user's contact details separately from their credit card details.
2. You shouldn't really use a `div` or a `fieldset` to enclose a submit button. The submit button relates to the entire form, rather than just certain fieldsets. If you simply want a device to position the submit button on its own line, you should look at styling it with CSS.

Comment: the problem with the submit button though is that it has to be enclosed in something in order to validate

Comment: @David: That's not the case. It sounds as though you have an error elsewhere in your markup which is giving misleading validations errors regarding the submit button. Can you post the code, or a link to your site?

Answer (score 1):

you should always use a fieldset element, along with its corresponding legend element. they add semantic information for users, but more importantly aid in accessibility for users with disabilities. i'm not positive what the one element you are using is, but i'll assume that it's a form control, and those should all be matched with label elements, providing similar benefits as the fieldset+legend elements. submit form controls should usually not be in a fieldset, because the fieldset is providing structure for grouped controls. i want to say i read somewhere it's bad practice, but i can't find it off hand, however i leave them out.